# Eclipse Java EE doesn't refresh my CSS files when running

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run my Java EE Application in Eclipse for Java EE developers, the pages don't refresh at all.

JSP pages and Java code (Servlets, Java classes, beans) do refresh, but CSS files remain the same (colors, font-size, etc)

I'm looking in the build path but I don't know what would be the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like the CSS is being cached - try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: @Kai you might also find [this](http://www.stefanhayden.com/blog/2006/04/03/css-caching-hack/) interesting

Comment: any other options, as a browser cache does nothing.   the only way I can (sometimes) get it to update is to, clean the project, edit the file (add a space to the end of the file), save it, refresh the file (from the sidebar), clean the project and then rebuild.  All of which is such a lengthy process for a simple CSS update.

Comment: okay seems it was caching for me too, even after a good purge in the browser.   If you're using Chrome, can I suggest (which I found worked like a treat), under the *Developer Tools* -> *Network* tab, there is an option to *Disable Cache* in the toolbar, under the tab.   This will make it that Chrome will always download a copy, which is good when rolling our to production as you don't have to turn on/off extra GET params to get around caching only for debugging.  :)